# How to use animation from .x file using DirectX and VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, directx

I want your help about creating animation in my VB.NET application. 
I created `.max` file and made some simple animation. Then I exported it to an `.x` file.
I can load this file in my application. But I have a problem using the animation which I created in my `.max` file and exported it to an `.x` file.
I googled about it but I couldn't find any useful information.

Could you help me about it by recommending any documentation or source code?

Comment: Could you be more specific on what exactly the problem is?

Comment: I want to use my animation from .x file. but i don't know where to start.

Comment: Take a look at the skinning demo in the old DX9 SDK.

Comment: This question has some potential to get negative feedback. Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: What I really need is detailed instructions on loading .x files and using things like direct3d animation sets to perform key frame animation.